# Dreamhost Cloud Computing: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS / Apache 2 listen multiple port

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, dreamhost

I'm configuring an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS within your DreamCompute service. I have installed apache2 and currently running successfully a website in port 80.

What I'm struggling now is to configure multiple websites with different ports.

When I try to access from Google Chrome to http://67.205.56.105:8080/, I get a connection refused error.

I describe everything I have checked and done below:

I created the file **/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.conf** (virtual host) aiming to the :8080 port:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin admin@interemplea-test.com
        ServerName interemplea-test
        ServerAlias test
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/web/
        <Directory "/var/www/html/prod/web/">
           AllowOverride All
       </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In /etc/apache2/ports.conf I added the 8080 port to be listened.

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
Listen 8000
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I have activated the virtual host with **a2ensite** command and **restarted and reloaded the apache service**. Also I checked in **/var/log/apache2/error.log** but only shows this:

```
[Fri Jul 24 20:15:58.336550 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10629] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jul 24 20:15:59.903414 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10687] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 24 20:15:59.903943 2015] [core:notice] [pid 10687] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

The symlink from sites-available appears correctly inside sites-enabled.

What Am I missing? Do I have set incorrectly some settings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing is to make sure it is actually listening, netstat -an | grep LIST can help you do that.  If it is listening on that port, then I would check whether there are port filters in the mix, either on the server or in the network infrastructure where the server is hosted.  This may be relevant (sorry, don't use them so not sure if this is something you would have for the level of service you are using):  http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Akanda_Networking

Answer (score 0):

As @Mary suggested, it was something related with the Dreamhost service, I had to add the port inside the DreamCompute dashboard. This link contains the instructions to create a rule to open the port: [Wiki Dreamhost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Access_%26_Security)

Also I mark in yellow the rule created inside my dashboard

[image]